# wpf: Maintain rectangle fill color on mouseenter / mouseleave

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `Grid` control to which I am dynamically adding rows that look as follows:

[image]

I want to highlight the row that has the mouse cursor over it. I'm currently doing this by adding a `Rectangle` to the row as the background, and changing its `Fill` property on `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`.

```c#
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
Grid.SetRow(rect, rowNum);
Grid.SetColumn(rect, colNum);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(rect, dataGrd_.ColumnDefinitions.Count);
rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
rect.MouseEnter += Rect_MouseEnter;
rect.MouseLeave += Rect_MouseLeave;
dataGrd_.Children.Add(rect);

private void Rect_MouseLeave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Rectangle).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}

private void Rect_MouseEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{    
    (sender as Rectangle).Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
}
```

The problem is that when the mouse moves over one of the controls in the foreground of the row, the `MouseLeave` event is triggered and the highlighting is lost.

Is there a way to have the highlighting persist as long as the mouse is within the bounds of the `Rectangle`, even if it's over a control that is in the foreground?

Also, the `MouseEnter` event isn't firing when the mouse enters the row, but is over a `Label` or another control. I suppose I can add event handlers to all of the controls, but that sounds excessive.

Since I'm adding these rows dynamically, I'm really only interested in code behind solutions, unless there's a way to achieve what I'm after in XAML.

Comment: Why you're not using a ListBox control, with ItemsSourse bound to ObservableCollection??? That way you'll have dynamic row updates on add/remove, and row highlight for free.(Not to mention that your code will be understandable for others).

Comment: @swiszcz I suppose the real answer is that I'm not a C# developer, so this solution wasn't apparent to me. I will look into using a `ListBox` so I appreciate the tip.

Comment: @swiszcz From what I could tell, the `ListBox` control only highlights the row on selection, not mouseover.

Comment: ListBox selection on MouseOver: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2616591/275330

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a reference to the `Rectangle`:

```
private Rectangle rect;
void ...()
{
    rect = new Rectangle();
    Grid.SetRow(rect, rowNum);
    Grid.SetColumn(rect, colNum);
    Grid.SetColumnSpan(rect, dataGrd_.ColumnDefinitions.Count);
    rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    rect.MouseEnter += Rect_MouseEnter;
    rect.MouseLeave += Rect_MouseLeave;
    dataGrd_.Children.Add(rect);
    dataGrd_.MouseEnter += dataGrd__MouseEnter;
    dataGrd_.MouseLeave += dataGrd__MouseLeave;
}
```

...and handle the same events for the parent `Grid` like this:

```
private void dataGrd__MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(rect);
    if (p.X > 0 && p.X <= rect.ActualWidth && p.Y > 0 && p.Y <= rect.ActualHeight)
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
}

private void dataGrd__MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point p = e.GetPosition(rect);
    if (p.X < 0 || p.X > rect.ActualWidth || p.Y < 0 || p.Y > rect.ActualHeight)
        rect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
}
```

Comment: There is 1 rectangle per row, so not sure how that would work with this solution.

Comment: Handle the MouseEnter/MouseLeave events for the row, whatever that is, then.